# What stages are in Kif's species life cycle?

Tags: futurama

How many stages of Kif's species does it take to become the swarm of bugs?  I know of three stages: tadpole, Kif's stage, and a swarm of bugs.

Does Kif's species have any other forms like the Decapodeans?

Answer (score 3):

The three stages you mention are the only three the writers of the show have as-yet revealed. If there are any more stages in the Ampibioid life-cycle, they have not yet been mentioned. One would assume Kif will eventually enter the same stage of life as is parents, but it is also never mentioned how long these life-stages last (except for the tadpole stage, which is established in the episode *Kif Gets Knocked Up A Notch*). Nor, for that matter, is Kif's age ever mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

We perhapes never find out. In futurama everything is variable, so maybe his parents are swarm of bugs but Kif is never to be changed. Or maybe is going to be revealed in some future episode.

Comment: Well, it's a comedy, so a lot of it isn't very consistent. E.g. Bender's metal composition is a running gag. However, the question is asking about his _species'_ life cycle, or at least the ones that have been revealed thus far. Whether he goes through all of them in the series is irrelevant. He doesn't have to be shown in a tadpole stage for his species to have that stage.